# Inconsistent reserve computation on UniswapV2

Tags: math, uniswap

I'm trying to process pool reserves on uniswapV2.

On the pool: WETH - USDC on UniswapV2.

address of the pool: `0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc`
https://etherscan.io/address/0xb4e16d0168e52d35cacd2c6185b44281ec28c9dc

I have this two consecutive swaps:

```
SWAP 0:
  transaction_hash = 0x07104ffdf32b06b90e604f23c7b4e21fc985b68c5bb8c13140d0d3d2e151a385
  block = 10370933
  log_index = 40
  dx = -3000.0 (USDC reserve pool variation)
  dy = 13.45013459746252 (WETH reserve pool variation)
```

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x07104ffdf32b06b90e604f23c7b4e21fc985b68c5bb8c13140d0d3d2e151a385

```
SWAP 1:
  transaction_hash = 0x9b0048c83a0a1a55d9de4966dc40eff15a97b58a54ecf4dff82409b525202b24
  block = 10370933
  log_index = 55
  dx = 1574.167134 (USDC reserve pool variation)
  dy = -7.0218022209976825 (WETH reserve pool variation)
```

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9b0048c83a0a1a55d9de4966dc40eff15a97b58a54ecf4dff82409b525202b24

This two swaps are consecutive (there are no swaps/mint/burn in between for this pool).

If I understand correctly how Uniswap V2 works, we have this set of equations:

```
X * Y = K
(X + dx0) * (Y + dy0) = K
(X + dx0 + dx1) * (Y + dy0 + dy1) = K
```

With X the initial reserves of token X, Y the initial reserves of token Y.
So I have 3 equations with 3 unknown variables (K, X, Y). After solving this equation system i get:

```
X = -(dy1 * dx0) * (dx0 + dx1) / (dx0*dy1 - dx1*dy0)
Y = -X * (dy0 / dx0) - dy0
```

Which gives on this example:

```
X = -279784.46893471375
Y = -1267.8297230812861
```

The result is obviously wrong (as reserves in pool can not be negative). **But why ?**

The formula does not work for swaps with different directions (in this example, sign of dx0 is different than sign of dx1).

But every time i use the formula for swaps with same direction, it works. Here is a plot, each point correspond reserves processed with consecutive swaps. In blue when swaps have same direction, black when swaps have different direction (same as example given):
[image: pool_reserves]

**Why this formula works for swaps with same direction and not for swaps with different directions ?**

**Is there a a way to get pool reserves with consecutive swaps with different direction ?**

Comment: You need to account for swap fees which changes the formula as explained in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72595515/12335762). Try this first. And have you verified that the pool reserves for same direction swaps are correct?

Comment: Reserves processed with two swaps with same direction are correct (it is the blue curve). I don't think taking into account fees is the reason why swaps with different direction gives invalid reserves because if it was, why would the formula give correct reserves for swaps with same direction without taking into accounts fees ?

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd like to figure that out this weekend. Can you provide in the question what the correct values for X and Y should be?